# Send a jwt token in my SSE event source (subscribe request)

Tags: javascript, dart, server-sent-events

How can I send a jwt token (or a header (Authorization to be specific)) in my SSE subscription request (the event source)?

```
void subscribe (String jwtToken) async {
  final eventSource = await html.EventSource("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authenticated/sse_subscription");
  eventSource.addEventListener("myEvent", (event) => {print(event)});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either cookies or url query string `http://127.0.0.1:8080/authenticated/sse_subscription?jwt=userjwt`

Comment: is there any better way? my all project take token from header, somewhere take token from url seems wired.

Comment: To my knowledge the original EventSource API has a few limitations including not being able to pass custom headers. If you want something with more customization you can take a look at the package [Fetch Event Source](https://github.com/Azure/fetch-event-source)